# C# Maui Registration of the App failed. Error 0x80070005

Tags: c#, .net, build, maui, windows-11

**The Problem**

When I try to build any Maui App, I always get following error message:
`DEP0700: Registration of the app failed. [0x80073CF6] Error 0x80070005: The AppContainer-Profile for the package "SomeRandomID" can not be created.`

Even on a new default created Project with no changes.

**What I tried**

I tried updating the Visual Studio templates and even Reinstalled Visual Studio

I tried checking the Windows rights on my drive / the project folder. SYSTEM and Admin have complete access, should be right.

I tried some online things I found with checking and deleting Assets references. Couldn't find any

**More Info**
Projects are just on my normal C drive. So not on a network drive or anything like that

My dotnet version: `7.0.100`

My Visual Studio version: `17.5.0 Preview 1`

My Windows version: `22H2`

**Weird**: It works on my laptop. But not on my PC. Both have the same dotnet and Visual Studio version. Laptop has Windows 10 though

Comment: When searching for this error I find a lot of results that this happens when you run the app from the network or a removable device and this is a restriction. Are you doing that by any chance?

Comment: ah i knew I forgot to add something. No I don't its just on my C Drive

Comment: Ok I found out that I also cant install Microsoft Store apps. So it has to do something with the permissions. Something is wrong. I'm running a system health scan right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the Solution. I read through so many sites but here I finally found the solution:
[error-0x80070005-updating-windows-store-apps](https://www.thewindowsclub.com/error-0x80070005-updating-windows-store-apps)